# Compatibility of effects implies compatibility of POVM's?

Tags: quantum-information, measurement-problem

Let $A = \{A_1 ,\ldots , A_n\}$ and $B = \{B_1 \ldots , B_n\}$ be two POVM's. Suppose every pair $(A_1, B_1)$ is jointly measurable as a couple of effects. 
Does this imply the joint-measurability of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: POVM = [positive-operator valued measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM)?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I thought it would be clear to whom is able to answer.

Comment: Are you including all pairs $(A_i,B_j)$, or only diagonal elements of the form $(A_j,B_j)$?

Comment: Any combination would suffice me actually, If I could show some kind of compatibility coming from the effects composing the POVM's it would help me.